# Scrapy:newbie attempts to pass the null value

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

When I practice scrapy I have a question,here is my code:

```
class MySpider(Spider):   
name = "yahoochart"
start_urls = ["https://tw.movies.yahoo.com/chart.html"]
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//tr'):
        ranking_list = sel.xpath("td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()
        print ranking_list
```

and the output will be:

[image]

I print put the sel (picture below) and know that cuz the first 3 line didn't math the          `sel.xpath("td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()` so it will print null value [] three times.
I want to know how to write can pass the null value (just prinit [u'1'] [u'2']...[u'20'])? or the only way is that I have to edit my first selector `response.xpath('//tr')`
Please teach me, thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a scrapy expert but it seems that it's an empty list rather than a 'null' value (which, in python, is named None)

You can check its length with

```
if ranking_list:
    print ranking_list
```

or

```
if len(ranking_list) > 0:
    print ranking_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a straightforward modification to your code. Just check to see whether `ranking_list` is empty or not before printing it.

```
for sel in response.xpath('//tr'):
    ranking_list = sel.xpath("td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()
    if ranking_list:
        print ranking_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work like this:

1) `for sel in response.xpath('//tr')` will get all `tr` tags from html page.

2) With each tag from the above, `sel.xpath("td[@class='c1']/span/text()").extract()` will look for `<td class="c1">`, then `<span>` tag, and then get text from `<span>` tag.

Check the page's source again, there're 3 `tr` tags that do not have all `<td class="c1">`, `<span>` (line 69, 224, 236). So when you `print` out, they'll be null.